# How to pass decimal values to stored procedure EF 6.1 without converting type error

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

I need to pass decimal\money to stored procedure from C#  using  EF 6.1 and get a result.
But I get the error:

> *System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Error converting data type **nvarchar** to **money**.*

**The SP looks like this:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateContractCash]   
        @UserId uniqueidentifier,
        -- other int params     
        @Year_01 money  -- cant convert this param

AS 
BEGIN 
-- some logic
SELECT 1 as StatusCode, 'Success' as StatusMessage -- result

END
```

**the repository code of Update method:**

```
 public new string Update(ContractCashSp entity)
        {
            var userId = new SqlParameter("UserId", entity.UserId);
            var year1 = new SqlParameter("Year_01", SqlDbType.Money) { Value = entity.CashContainer.Year1, Precision = 10, Scale = 2};

            string procedureQuery = string.Format("exec spUpdateContractCash @UserId, @Year_01");

            IList<object> paramsList = new List<object>();
            paramsList.Add(userId);
            paramsList.Add(year1);

            StoredProcedureResult result = ExecuteSqlQuery(procedureQuery, paramsList.ToArray()).First();

            return result.StatusMessage;
        }

protected DbRawSqlQuery<StoredProcedureResult>  ExecuteSqlQuery(string procedureQuery, object[] parameters)
        {
            return dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<StoredProcedureResult>(procedureQuery, parameters);
        }
```

**Trace of the SQL request show next:**

```
exec sp_executesql N'spUpdateContractCash @UserId, @Year_01',
 N'@UserId uniqueidentifier,
 @Year_01 money',
 @UserId='15352797-B907-49EA-9120-34BBB8DFA1DD',
 @Year_01=$334785.0000
```

How to pass decimal values to stored procedure and reduces this problem?

Comment: what is the type of `entity.CashContainer.Year1` ?

Comment: The type is decimal. Error apperas while execution.